# .NET6 based win forms application Could not copy from..to .Exceeded retry count of 10

Tags: winforms, .net-6.0

I have a Winforms based application which is in .NET6 framework. I have sorted all compliation issues. Once I am building , I am getting, the following error
Error MSB3027   Could not copy "obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\WinFormsAppNet6.dll" to "bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\WinFormsAppNet6.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "WinFormsAppNet6 (27096)"   WinFormsAppNet6 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    4702

I have done re-builds and removed obj and bin folders(The exce did not get deleted) but still I am getting this error.
The same code runs in 4.7.2 .NET framework based app.

This is very strange. Is that any special settings required? I also saw something new, a new folder with name "runtimes" gets added. Please refer the following screen shot.
[image]

In build, I have selected "Any CPU".

Any pointers would be very helpfull.

best regards,
S

Comment: Your app got stuck and the executable remains, orphaned, in memory. Check with TaskManager -- If you have foreground Threads running, remove them

Comment: Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.  In general you'll want an exclusion for your project directories.

Comment: I am aware the things mentioned by Jimi and Hans Prashant but seems something else is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I re-started my system and all i working fine. Old age windows problem.

This is strange.